# Update sql bit field in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In a sql table I have a bit field and the value is displayed as True, when I update in code  `Update table1 set Active='True'` it makes the update but the value is now displayed as `1` instead of `True`. How do I make it put the value `'True'` instead of the integer in the table? Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS and what is displaying the value as `True` and then `1`?

Comment: it's seql version 10.50.1600.1, when i open the table to view the existing data the value is True in the Active(bit) field. Now when i do an update in management studio thru a query, it sets that value to 1. So my old value in the table is now 1 instead of True.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Bits` in SQL Server are always stored as `1` or `0` in a bitmap.

The "Edit Table" option in SSMS just translates this to `True` or `False` for presentation purposes, this is nothing to do with how it is actually stored.

Comment: Was getting confused when doing a select query.

Comment: @user - Yes. If you wanted it returned as a string you would need to do `CASE Col when 1 THEN 'True' WHEN 0 THEN 'False' END` or apply such formatting in the presentation layer.